# Regionwide vs Region maps

Tags: maps, osmand

Question regarding Osmand+ application. Will I miss something in case I download regionwide maps and don't download region maps. As far as I understood regionwide maps should cover all regions. I'm right?

Comment: Regarding Osmand application. Bassically it is based on OSM, so question in general is regarding OSM maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, except that region maps are based on administrative divisions

**[Source](https://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html)**

> Geographic Regions
>
> Data on the download server is organised by region. The /openstreetmap directory contains files that have a whole continent's data in them, and for some continents there are subdirectories in which you find individual files for various countries. Some countries again have their own subdirectories with data for administrative subdivisions. For Germany, all "Bundesländer" are available as separate files, and for England we have many individual counties.